# emacsclientw does not use font specified in init.el (Windows)

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, emacsclient, fonts, server

**Emacs version:** GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

I have set up a shell-script which runs Emacs server at Windows startup as mentioned in [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration#toc8). I have set up a shortcut on my desktop which I can double-click to run `emacsclientw.exe` with this command

```
H:\emacs-25.3-x86_64\bin\emacsclientw.exe -n -c -a ""
```

But `emacsclientw.exe` does **not** use the font I have specified in my `init.el`. This is strange, since everything else in my `init.el` works **perfectly** (macros, packages, etc).

How do I get `emacsclientw.exe` to use the font I have set up in my `init.el`?

I have this Elisp code in my `init.el` to set font and frame size on startup

```
;; Select a desirable font-size, frame position and frame size when Emacs starts up
(defun originalPosition ()
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-font "Courier New-14" t t)
  (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 100 50)
  (when window-system (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 82 28))
  )
(originalPosition)
```

Comment: Same problem here with Emacs 26.2, though not always. Sometimes Emacs daemon seems to catch up the right font. Interestingly, I'm experiencing no such issues at all with `runemacs.exe`.

Comment: @Timm Exactly! Earlier I would start Emacs with runemacs.exe and never had this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `default-frame-alist` and it solves the issue.

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Courier New-14")) ;; Font type & size
```

It is guaranteed to work, whether Emacs is launched normally or as a daemon.